# Как переназначить hotkeys

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Проблема в следующем:
Если пытаться переназначить хоткей в настройках, в разделе клавиатура, то при нажате на поле, ничего не появляется ( верней появляется, но это можно разглядеть по едва-едва размытию фона ), то самое окошко, в котором надо вводить новое сочитание клавиш для хоткея. Если пытаться ввести хоткей, когда она, якобы, появилось, то ничего не происходит. И его можно закрыть через Esc.

А другой информации в интернете, как переназначить хоткей, я не нашел. Не знаю, как отследить шаблон, для этого хоткея, чтобы заменить через xmodmap.

Меня интересует переназначение "Move to workspace above" со стандартного Super+PageUp на Super+Q

На данный момент, сочитание Super+A у меня назначено на "Move to workspace down" и через утилиту XEV для него я получаю следующее:

```
    PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
        atom 0x182 (WM_STATE), time 4597905, state PropertyNewValue

    PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
        atom 0x146 (_NET_WM_STATE), time 4597905, state PropertyNewValue

    PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
        atom 0x192 (_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS), time 4597905, state PropertyNewValue

    PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
        atom 0x182 (WM_STATE), time 4599248, state PropertyNewValue

    PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
        atom 0x146 (_NET_WM_STATE), time 4599248, state PropertyNewValue

    PropertyNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
        atom 0x192 (_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS), time 4599248, state PropertyNewValue
```

Для сочитания клавиш Super+Q получаю:

```
    FocusOut event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
        mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

    FocusIn event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
        mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

    KeymapNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
        keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
               0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

p.s. Либо может есть сторонняя утилита схожая со штатными средствами?
p.s.s. Или как можно попробовать отследить проблему окна в настройках?
p.s.s.s. Из системы ничего не удалял ни вручную, ни через менеджер пакетов, ибо система после недавнего, случайного, краха была установлена с нуля